# how to add a collection of data into another collection using a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to display records of different entities relating to a single entity.

A tenant for example has a collection of rents, rents in turn have collection of payments.
I want to display in the view, all tenants with the rents and payments.

Here is my current implementation in my view.

```
@foreach (var t in Model.Tenants)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@t.Fullname</td>
        @foreach (var rents in t.Rents)
        {
            <td>@rents.Apartment.BedroomType</td>
            <td>@rents.Apartment.MonthlyFee.ToString("N0")</td>
            <td>@($"{@rents.Total.ToString("N0")}/{@rents.Type}")</td>
            <td>@($"{@rents.DueDate.ToString("MMM yyy")}")</td>
            foreach (var payments in rents.Payments)
            {
                <td>@payments.PaymentDate.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy")</td>
                <td>@payments.AmountPaid.ToString("N0")</td>
                <td>@payments.Balance</td>
            }
        }
    </tr>
}
```

This currently works fine but I don't want to be doing lots of filtering on the client which I think its not a good practice, so I want to move the logic to my controller to handle all filtering of records.

What I want to  do is change this implementation using a list and add each collection into its own list. Payments for instance would be in its own list relating to its rent. Rents would be in its own list relating to the specific tenant. By doing this I can maybe filter rents based on rental status or only show payments that have been actually paid. This current implementation does not give me that.

I could really use some help with guidelines here...

Comment: What do you mean by _filtering on the frontend_? As far as I can see - you are doing no filtering whatsoever. Clarify for me please what desired result would be - do you want to have 3 separate lists, one with tenants, one with rents and one with payments? How exactly do you want to display those lists?

Comment: Also, is the server who render that logic on the client.....

Answer (score 0):

I would say you just need to make a small change. In your view model, have a list of payments instead of tenants (do it the other way round). Have a look at the example below for an idea of what I mean:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string bedRoomType = "", double amountPaid = 0)
    {
        var viewModel = new TenantIndexVm();
        using (var context = new RentEntities())
        {                
            viewModel.Payments = context.Payment.Where(x => (x.Rent.BedRoomType == bedRoomType || bedRoomType == "") && (x.AmountPaid >= amountPaid)).Include("Rent.Tenant");
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

In the view, you would loop through the payments:

```html
@foreach (var p in Model.Payments)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@p.Rent.Tenant.Fullname</td>
        <td>@p.Rent.Apartment.BedroomType</td>
        <td>@p.Rent.Apartment.MonthlyFee.ToString("N0")</td>
        <td>@($"{@p.Rent.Total.ToString("N0")}/{@p.Rent.Type}")</td>
        <td>@($"{@p.Rent.DueDate.ToString("MMM yyy")}")</td>
        <td>@p.PaymentDate.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy")</td>
        <td>@p.AmountPaid.ToString("N0")</td>
        <td>@p.Balance</td>
    </tr>
}
```